# I can not insert into MariaDB table with my PHP script

Tags: php, sql-insert, mariadb

I recently moved to MariaDB, because since MySQL 5.6 it has been failing a lot for me.

MariaDB works flawlessly but, in a new project, I cannot insert data to the database with a PHP script. I can only insert manually. I have made no changes from scripts working with MySQL.

The INSERT statement is:

```
INSERT INTO participantes (nome, curso, email, equipe) VALUES (:nome, :curso, :email, :equipe);
```

And the script which should be inserting is:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($this->SQL_INSERT);
$nome = $participante->nome();
$curso = $participante->curso();
$email = $participante->email();
$equipe = $participante->equipe();
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':curso', $curso);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':equipe', $equipe);
$stmt->execute();
```

The "participante" functions return data to be used, with no problems. Everything is inside a try/catch block, which reports no exceptions.

My PDO class is as follows:

```
class Connection extends PDO {
    private $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=dacu';
    private $usr = 'dacu';
    private $pwd = 'my password';

    public $handle = null;

    function __construct() {
        try {
            if ($this->handle == null) {
                $dbh = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->usr, $this->pwd);
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->handle = $dbh;
                return $this->handle;
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception('Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception('Um erro não identificado ocorreu: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And using controller->insert gives me:

```
Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called in C:\Webserver\Files\dacu\controller\EquipesController.php on line 25
```

I can post code on pastebin if necessary, just ask.

Comment: Not "php" but "*my code* not inserting to MariaDB table"

Comment: If you like to get a codereivew of your code, it is probably better suited on the code-review site. This website here works best for concrete programming questions.

Comment: Are all referenced columns strings in the database?

Comment: Duplicate of [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, I double checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connection, then try this way, its working fine:

```
    //first you need a connection to mysql use this and replace the variables

        try {
          $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db_name.'', $user, $pass, array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        ));
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }

    //then do the insert variable

        $sql  = 'INSERT INTO encomendas (`nome`, `user`, `id`, `email`) ';
        $sql .= 'VALUES (:nome, :curso, :email, :equipe )';


        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    //bindParam with your own variables

        $query->bindParam(':nome', $varDoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':curso',  $varDoCurso, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $varDoEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':equipe', $varDaequipe, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //execute query

        $query->execute()

;
```

Comment: It's kinda the same I use... except "setAttribute" gets an error for me.

Comment: what error do you get? the setAttribute in that case is setting to display errors check http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php for more about it.

Comment: probably the error that it throws, is why your query dont insert!

Comment: but the user Your Common Sense has already pointed that and as very good response in the fist comments!! check that out!

Comment: I tested every line of code again and found the error. There are no PDO/DB errors anymore, this piece of code solved the problem. The fault is now on my code, already fixed!